# Tomcat - nested webapp pathing without using Apache HTTPD

Tags: java, tomcat, path, war, contextpath

I'm again trying things I probably shouldn't... but... usually I get the feeling it's possible. This time, I'm really crossing my fingers.

I have a Tomcat 8 instance. On this instance, I have:

- AppA (WAR) - Primary web application
- AppB (WAR) - Secondary sub-application (more of a feature really) but people will access using an special path (like "service").

I **don't** want to run Apache HTTPD (or any other additional service layers). I also want to make this seemless at the tomcat level instead of trying to fake it via ingress networking/waf/etc or through the application itself (allow developer to work on other needed coding).

What I really want is to configure Tomcat in a way that will handle this by itself:

- A user can visit https://host.com/AppA
- A user can use the feature if they go to https://host.com/AppA/service (which points to AppB, but the user should never see the WAR name of "AppB" - changing the WAR name to "service" is perfectly acceptable if that saves some sanity)

Now I tried following the Virtual Host configuration (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html) with little changes here to see if I can make this fit what I need... and... it's failing, but I think that if tomcat can do this, I can get it there.

What I've tried so far:

- Updated [tomcat]/conf/**server.xml** with an added  entry.
- Added a new "webapps"-like folder called [tomcat]/**AppBapp** (AppB.war sits here)
- Added a [tomcat]/conf/Catalina/localhost/**AppB.xml** context file.

I've seen a few posts where they kind of do this, but in the opposite direction (root web directory points to some custom server path). I think I can get this config figured out, but I have to ask... will this strategy even work for what I'm trying to do with tomcat? Or am I in the wrong ballpark completely?

Thanks a bunch for your time. Always Appreciated!

Comment: write the code so far AppA/servlet calls AppB/resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you want *nested contexts* by Tomcat configuration only.

This was talked about on the [Tomcat User's List](http://tomcat.apache.org/lists.html#tomcat-users) and you can have a look at this [archived thread](https://tomcat.markmail.org/search/?q=nested%20list%3Aorg.apache.tomcat.users#query:nested%20list%3Aorg.apache.tomcat.users%20page:2%20mid:ekn2mp53kx5aootp%20state:results) about *nested contexts*.

From my understanding, the solution given relies on two contexts configuration :

```
$TOMCAT_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/A.xml
$TOMCAT_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/A#service.xml
```

with directories `webapps/A` and `webapps/A#service` (this one containing the deployed appB content).

Comment: I'm not sure how I missed posts about that... but that's **perfectly** what I'm aiming for. Thanks @eugène-adell !